# Site direction base on language in laravel

Tags: laravel, right-to-left

I'm working with laravel 5.4 and my application supports both LTR and RTL languages, my question is how can I redirect my content when user choose RTL language and reverse of it obviously?

Comment: Right to Left like (Persian, Arabic, Hebrew), LTR like (English)

Answer (score 3):

I had same question and after some investigations i did following process:

1. added following code to my language file:

   'page_direction' => 'rtl',

you can learn more about this subject on [Laravel Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization) documentations.

2. After this added following code to my master template:

   class="{{ __('global.page_direction') }}"
3. At this time i can define special CSS code when body element have rtl class like this:

   body.rtl .element{float:right}

Answer (score 0):

You'll want look in to incorporating Laravel's localization features for this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization

Each language has it's translated phrases stored in the resources/lang directory. Then based on the user's browser settings the application will display the correct translated text.

Comment: No man, I have translation languages it works fine my issue is just about page direction.

Comment: If it is just the text direction you are needing changed, then consider using the css direction property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp. You can then set the correct element class based on the user's localization.

Answer (score 0):

You may try writing an JS function for `onchange` event of `RTL` or `LTR`

```
$(document).on('change', '#language_selector' , function() {
    var locale = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('change_language') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            locale: locale
        },
        success: function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

and attach a route to set the locale

```
Route::post('change_language', function() {
    $locale = Input::get('locale');
    App::setLocale($locale);
});
```

and in your view based on the locale you could set the style css

```
 @if(App::getLocale() == 'en')
 <link href="ltr.css" type="stylesheet" />
 @else
 <link href="rtl.css" type="stylesheet" />
 @endif
```